# mkfs.xfs /dev/custom_dev

Tags: linux, ubuntu, xfs

I try to format a custom block device with `mkfs.xfs` in Ubuntu Server 12.04 LTS.
In the end terminal prints:

```
cache_node_put: node put on refcount 0 (node=0x1cd7810)  
cache_node_put:node put on node (0x1cd7810) in MRU list
```

and fails.

I do not have any problem with the other filesystems such as `ext2`. Only `xfs` returns that.

`dmesg` prints

```
segfault at 10 ip ........ sp ..... error 4 in libc-2.15.so[...]
```

The full command is `sudo mkfs.xfs /dev/custom_dev`. When I use the same command with the `-f` flag, the terminal prints at the end:

```
*** glibc detected *** mkfs.xfs: free(): invalid pointer: 0x0000000002431600 ***
*** glibc detected *** mkfs.xfs: malloc(): memory corruption: 0x000000000243170 ***
```

I use Ubuntu Server 12.04 LTS.

The full command is "sudo mkfs.xfs /dev/custom_dev". When i use the same command with flag -f (sudo mkfs.xfs -f /dev/custom_dev) the terminal prints in the end
"* glibc detected mkfs.xfs: free(): invalid pointer: 0x0000000002431600 glibc detected mkfs.xfs: malloc(): memory corruption: 0x000000000243170 * and does not return(unless i hit ^C)

I tested mkfs.xfs in another device and i have no problem. The problem remains in custom_dev only in which  i use a simple device driver i wrote on my own. The custom_dev does not seem to have any problem with ext2. Only with xfs. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

It would appear your issue is a bug in your copy of mkfs.xfs. While I can't be certain without more details from you (which version of ubuntu, which version of the xfsprogs package), I suspect it's highly likely. The bug appears to have been addressed late last year:

http://oss.sgi.com/archives/xfs/2013-09/msg00814.html
http://www.spinics.net/lists/xfs/msg23311.html

I'd recommend upgrading (or, possibly, downgrading) your xfsprogs package.

Good Luck.